# Workflow Task Process - email notifications

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity, designer-workflow

Is there any way to display the consolidated comments for task process in descending order for an approval workflow ?

The comments are included in task notification emails. i could not find any obivious properties for [%Task Process:Consolidated Comments%] in sharepoint designer.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Your question and the problem at hand isn't very clear. Can you provide more information on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: thanks for your response. I have a custom workflow with multiple approval process with in it. the task email notification has [%Task Process:Consolidated Comments%]. all i want is to display these comments in decending order rather than in ascending order

Answer (score 1):

The Approval Process has a "Properties" option whenever you use the SPD Action Menu.

This can specify the Comments in a variable, that you can use later in the workflow.